# An inequality for completely positive maps.

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $f\colon A\to B$ be a contractive [completely positive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choi%27s_theorem_on_completely_positive_maps), ${}^*$-preserving map between C*-algebras and take $a\in A$. How one can prove that
$$0\leqslant f(a)f(a^*)\leqslant f(aa^*)?$$
Some authors take it for granted without any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most important results about completely positive maps is [Stinespring's Dilation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinespring_factorization_theorem).

Suppose that $f:A \to B$ is a completely positive map, where $A$ and $B$ are $C^*$-algebras. Then we can find a Hilbert space $H$ such that $B \subseteq B(H)$.

Stinespring's Theorem then states that there exists a Hilbert space $K$,  $*$-homomorphism $\pi: A \to B(K)$, and a bounded operator $V: H \to K$ such that 
$$
f(a)= V \pi(a) V^*,
$$
with $\Vert f \Vert = \Vert V \Vert^2$.

The desired inequality now follows easily:
\begin{array}{ccc}
f(aa^*)& =& V \pi(aa^*) V^* \\
   &= &V \pi(a) \pi(a^*) V^* \\
   & \geq &V \pi(a) V^* V \pi(a^*) V^* \\
    &= &f(a) f(a^*).
\end{array}
Here we use that $ V^*V \leq \Vert V \Vert^2 1 \leq \Vert f \Vert \leq 1$ because $f$ is contractive.

In fact, one can prove this result only using the weaker hypothesis that $f$ is $2$-positive. This is known as [Kadison's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Kadison.E2.80.93Schwarz_inequality).

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, the matrix trick mentioned in the answer by @Tom Cooney:

Assume $A$ is unital. If not, extend $f$ to unitization of $A$.

For any $a \in A$,

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & a^*\\
a & aa^*
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

is positive in $M_2(A)$. The $2$-positivity of $f$ then tells you

$$
f(a) f(a^*) \leq f(aa^*).
$$